# What is the Sampling + license?

Tags: sample, license

In a site where i wanted to download a sound track to use in my project, i read that the license of that sound says:

"This work is licensed under the Sampling+ License."
[link](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/sampling+/1.0/)

What does this mean exactly? can't i use this item for commercial use?

Answer (score 2):

**Commercial use:** You need to alter it significantly or mix with other sounds to the point that we can say it is a new creation.

**Noncommercial use:** You can use it analtered.

**In both cases:**

- You need to give attribution to the creator.
- You can't use the track to advertise or promote anything other than your new work. This says that there is **no way** to use it to create jingles for tv/radio ad. or movie trailer music etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the license says, you can't use it directly for commercial use without altering it, but if you use it as a sample that you make creative changes to, then it is authorized for commercial use as a portion of your own artistic creation, provided that you give attribution to the original creator for their portion of the work.